# Android ExpandableListActivity Icons random disappear

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-imageview

I have an Activity which extends ExpandableListActivity and which contains some Parent Groups and some Child Entries...
Left of the entries inside the groups i put an icon. Whenever I open an entry it randomly takes out icons and it's not showing them anymore... I couldn't find a pattern there so I'm not quite sure where my mistake is (Maybe I am recycling my objects the wrong way?!)

Here is my BaseExpandableListAdapter:

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
        }

        TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        tvName .setText(arrChildelements[groupPosition][childPosition]);
        ImageView tvIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIcon);

        switch (childPosition) {
            case 0:
                tvIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_1);
                break;
            case 1:
                tvIcon.setAlpha(0);
                break;
            case 2:
                tvIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_2);
                break;
            case 3:
                tvIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_3);
                break;
            case 4:
                tvIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_4);
                break;
            case 5:
                tvIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_5);
                break;
            case 6:
                tvIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_6);
                break;
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

And here is my child_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you need any additional information and/or code, please let me know!

Thanks in advance for your help and please excuse my english...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it because `tvIcon.setAlpha(0);` and `ListView` optimalization ... 
you should set alpha to 1 in other cases (`tvIcon.setAlpha(1);` before switch statment)...

Edit:

or instead `tvIcon.setAlpha(0);` try `tvIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty);`

Comment: I did set the Alpha value to 1 now but I'm still facing the same issue... Anything that could help?

Edit: Your edit actually fixed it... Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

```
tvIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.video_icon);
```

try this one

Comment: This didn't work. Am I right if I put this on every single one?

Comment: [programming by permutation ?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_by_permutation)

Comment: Ah sorry I put that on onto every other and not replaced the setAlpha with this one...

Comment: you can this code u use in listView ,u can set Adapter in list

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of view recycling.  You can fix it like so:

1) Declare an array to hold the necessary information in your adapter

```
private int iconArray[][];
```

2) Populate the array immediately upon the adapter being called:

```
iconArray = new int[arrChildelements.length][6];
int i=0;
int j=0;
for (i; i < arrChildelements.length; i++) {
    for (j; j < arrChildelements[i].length; j++) {
        arrChildelements[i][j] = j;
    }
}
```

3) Use this array to set the icons like so:

```
    switch (iconArray[groupPosition][childPosition]) {
        case 0:
            tvIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_1);
            break;
        case 1:
            tvIcon.setAlpha(0);
            break;
        case 2:
            tvIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_2);
            break;
        case 3:
            tvIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_3);
            break;
        case 4:
            tvIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_4);
            break;
        case 5:
            tvIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_5);
            break;
        case 6:
            tvIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_6);
            break;
    }
```

Note that I hardcoded 6 as the number of child elements for each group as that is the number of switches you show in your code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for this long and helpful answer! I was already able to fix the problem with the other answers though. Thanks again anyway!